# Microsoft Access Query to SUM & SORT in a query

Tags: ms-access, sorting, sum

```
SELECT ptMeds.Station, ptMeds.TxDate, ptMeds.PaType, ptMeds.GenMedName, 
ptMeds.Strength, ptMeds.UnitsM, ptMeds.Volume, ptMeds.Dosage
FROM ptMeds
WHERE (((ptMeds.Station)="EMER1") AND ((ptMeds.PaType)="WITHDRAWN")) <I will need to look at the GenMedName field here also>
GROUP BY ptMeds.GenMedName;
```

I need to be able to SUM based on ptMeds.GenMedName and then sort the results highest to lowest.  I've looked thru other responses to similar question but cannot find exactly what I need to do.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of what what you expect the result set to look like? What field(s) do you want to sum?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ptMeds.Station, ptMeds.TxDate, ptMeds.PaType, ptMeds.GenMedName, 
ptMeds.Strength, ptMeds.UnitsM, ptMeds.Volume, ptMeds.Dosage
FROM ptMeds
WHERE (((ptMeds.Station)="EMER1") AND ((ptMeds.PaType)="WITHDRAWN")) 
GROUP BY ptMeds.GenMedName
ORDER BY ptMeds.GenMedName DESC;
```